# Is unattended-upgrades performing dist-upgrade on Ubuntu LTS 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, lts, unattended-upgrades

I noticed the following line in *unattended-upgrades.log* file (on my **dev** instance where I have *unattended-upgrades* service enabled and configured to install only security updates):

```
> 2020-02-19 06:49:20,723 INFO Packages that will be upgraded: libpq5 linux-aws linux-headers-aws linux-image-aws postgresql-client-10
```

**Production** instance has *unattended-upgrades* service disabled because security upgrades are manually installed over there in a controlled manner. But when doing a manual check for **apt-get upgrade only** I don't see the above packages:

```
$ apt-get -s upgrade |grep "^Inst" |grep -i securi | awk '{print $2}'
libpq-dev
libpq5
linux-libc-dev
postgresql-client-10
```

Now, when I modify the statement to list **dist-upgrade** packages, I can see those kernel related:

```
$ apt-get -s dist-upgrade |grep "^Inst" |grep -i securi | awk '{print $2}'
libpq-dev
libpq5
linux-modules-4.15.0-1060-aws
linux-image-4.15.0-1060-aws
linux-aws
linux-image-aws
linux-aws-headers-4.15.0-1060
linux-headers-4.15.0-1060-aws
linux-headers-aws
linux-libc-dev
postgresql-client-10
```

That leads me to a conclusion that *unattended-upgrades* service is indeed performing dist-upgrade by default.

Can somebody confirm this with me? And if this is true then how could I prevent unattended-upgrades from executing dist-upgrades automatically?

Thanks

Comment: Try checking for an apt *full-upgrade* instead of a *dist-upgrade*. Packages with version numbers baked into the name (like kernels) cannot by upgraded by an apt-upgrade, which is why the dist-/full-upgrade is done instead. There is no setting to change among upgrade/dist-/full- .

Comment: Yep, I guess dist-upgrade should be safe enough if `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` is configured to allow only for security updates, which it is by default. Thanks